# Avoid overlap caused by dynamic resizing in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, kivy

I'm working on a `GridLayout` (here called `CostosInput`) that adds `TextInputs` to itself when a button is pressed. However, when it does, the layout doesn't resize the widgets around it, which causes it to overlap once a certain amount of `TextInput` widgets are added. How can I fix that?

It is part of another `GridLayout`, which has one column and is contained in a `ScrollView`. The widget below it (the one it overlaps with) is a `Label`.

I've tried looking in the Kivy docs, but the only stuff I've found is related to the size of `Layouts` and `Widgets`, and not necessarily their placement. I thought it'd be something like the `layout_hint_with_bounds(sh_sum, available_space, min_bounded_size, sh_min_vals, sh_max_vals, hint)` [(link to the Kivy docs)](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#), but that's an internal function. I apologize if something doesn't conform to convention.

Here's the code for the `CostoInput` class.

```
class CostosInput(GridLayout):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CostosInput, self).__init__()
    self.cols = 2
    self.spacing = 5
    self.padding = 5
    self.size_hint_y = 0.2

    # used in add_lines()
    self.count = 1

    add = Orange_Button(text='AGREGAR COSTO')
    add.bind(on_press=self.add_lines)

    rem = Orange_Button(text='QUITAR COSTO')
    rem.bind(on_press=self.del_lines)

    self.add_widget(add)
    self.add_widget(rem)

    self.add_widget(Orange_Label(text='concepto'))
    self.add_widget(Orange_Label(text='costo'))

    self.add_lines()

# this function is adds TextInputs
# when the add button is pressed
def add_lines(self, *args, **kwargs):
    text = Normal_TI()
    text.text = 'costo ' + str(self.count)
    text.bind(text=self.change)
    flot = FloatInput()
    flot.bind(text=self.change)
    self.add_widget(text)
    self.add_widget(flot)
    self.size_hint_y += 0.1

    self.count += 1

# this has nothing to do with the ui
def del_lines(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for x in range(0, len(self.children) - 4, 2):
        if len(self.children) > 4:
            try:
                if self.children[x].focus or self.children[x + 1].focus:
                    self.remove_widget(self.children[x])
                    self.remove_widget(self.children[x])
            except Exception as err:
                print('del lines: no se pudieron quitar,'
                      'err {}'.format(err))

# this also has nothing to do with the ui
def change(self, value, *args):
    dicto = dict()
    for x in range(0, len(self.children) - 4, 2):
        dicto[self.children[x + 1].text] = self.children[x].text
    print(dicto)
    producto.costos = dicto
```

Here's the code for the class the label is instantiated with. The text attribute is the only part that changes.

```
class Orange_Label(Label):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Orange_Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.size_hint_y = None
    self.size = (self.width, 10)
    self.color = (0.95668627451, 0.6941176471, 0.5137254902, 1)
```

Comment: The `GridLayout` will normally adjust the size of its children (in your case, by decreasing their height) when children are added. Do your `Normal_TI` and `FloatInput` widgets have fixed heights (as your `OrangeLabel` does)?

Comment: @JohnAnderson They do have fixed heights, both at 30.

Comment: So that means that the `GridLayout` cannot adjust the height of those fixed height widgets and will therefor run out of space at some point. Some options at that point are to resize the `GridLayout`, or use a [ScrollView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html) to contain the `GridLayout`, or to adjust the size of the `App`. The `ScrollView` approach is the most flexible.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thank you! The `GridLayout` is actually contained in a `ScrollView`, but I'm not sure how I could go about resizing it. I think that's the main problem. I thought it would automatically resize with the `minimum_height` property, but I don't know what has to happen so it updates itself.

Comment: If your `GridLayout` (`CostosInput`) is in a `ScrollView`, then you shouldn't need to worry about resizing, and it shouldn't overlap with other widgets. When you add many new lines, you should be able to scroll through them without affecting other widgets. Is that how your app is working?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your previous comment. `CostosInput` is part of another `GridLayout`, which is the one in the `ScrollView`. `CostosInput` is not immediately contained in a `ScrollView`. I think that could be a good workaround, but I was interested in knowing whether I can automatically resize the rest of the widgets so I can still display the entire `CostosInput` without overlap. Otherwise, I think adding it to a `ScrollView` would be a great solution. Thank you!